# jQuery pass to input value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pass an id to hidden input value. Id is returning right value but not passing to target input value

```
$('.delete-customer').click(function(){
    var cust_id = $(this).children().attr('id');
    var target = $('#remove-item').val();

    $(target).text(cust_id);
});
```

hidden input:

```
<input id="remove-item" type="hidden" name="cid" value="" />
```

Comment: It should be `$('#remove-item').val(cust_id);` Learn how those methods work before using them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.target-val').val(cust_id);
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

```
var target = $('#remove-item').val();
$(target).text(cust_id);
```

What are you trying to achieve here? The above code gets the value from an element with id, "remove-item"

Then jQuery tries to select an item which matches the value returned by the previously selected item (the value of element with id "remove-item")

Depending upon, what the value is, the element would be selected and text would be put in. 
That element may or may not exist.

May be this is what you are trying to achieve

```
var target = $('#remove-item');
    $(target).text(cust_id);
```

The above can be combined and you can also use:

```
$('#remove-item').text(cust_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var target = $('#remove-item').val();
$(target).text(cust_id);
```

to

```
$('#remove-item').val(cust_id);
```